# user-space starvation under heavy traffic

Tags: network-programming, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I'm implementing a user-space embedded configuration manager application and a network device driver on linux gateway device. 
 We encountered the following issue: under heavy TCP traffic with CPU load ~100% the manager application is starved : it fails to send management commands from user space to the network driver - command time out occurs. The requirement is to be able to send commands even if it causes throughput degradation. How can this be solved? 
Here are some details on our system: kernel 2.6.35, preemption disabled, network driver is processing incoming packets in interrupt context

Comment: *"the manager application is starved "* - starved of what, memory? What do these programs do when a `malloc()` fails?  Do they lamely loop to perform a retry? Or at least delay or `sched_yield()` before retrying?  Do they ever report when memory requests fail?

Comment: It is pretty obvious that the question is about CPU starvation, not memory, unless you were trying to answer your own thoughts.

Comment: I meant the CPU starvation, sorry: the command sending fails on timeout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options, the good and the ugly ones (I haven't thought about the bad one yet):
1. Move interrupts to threads - http://lwn.net/Articles/302043/
2. Interrupt pacing